# How can I copy a specific column from multiple worksheets to a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains 300 sheets Jan1990, Feb1990,....Dec2016.

Each sheet contains data in column A1:AS11 and I want only AR column Data (11 rows in each column) from all 300 sheets in the sheet named as "Masters".

I found one code on the forum but I need to change the sheet name again and again to get the data in the below code. Also AR column contain formula so I need the Value only not the formula.

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

    'set your sheets here
    Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEP2014")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    rowCntr = 1

    'get last rows from both sheets
    lastRowInput = inputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = inputWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'copy data from columns AR, AS
    inputWS.Range("AR1:AR11" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1)
    

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop through all worksheets that are not named "Master."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited your code .. As suggested by BigBen it contains a loop to copy AR Columns from all sheets other than Master. It is pasted one below the previous in the F column of the master sheet as per your code. You can also paste them side by side. Assuming 'Master' sheet is Sheet(1), loop starts with i = 2 i.e. Sheet(2)

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim path As String, fileName As String
Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

'set your sheets here
'Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEP2014")
Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
rowCntr = 1

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name <> "Master" Then
Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

'get last rows from both sheets
lastRowInput = inputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = inputWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'copy data from columns AR, AS
'inputWS.Range("AR1:AR11" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1)

' to paste them one below the prevous.
inputWS.Range("AR1:AR" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1)


' to paste them side by side from F column.
'inputWS.Range("AR1:AR" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Cells(1, 4 + i)

End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @NareshBhople it worked. much appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change required, pass the worksheet name into your sub, then in another sub loop on a list of sheet names:

```
Sub LoopOnSheets()

dim sheetNames() as string
dim x as integer

sheetNames = split("sheet name one,sheet name two,and so on",",") ' list your sheets here separated by a comma

for x = 0 to ubound(sheetNames) - 1
   Demo Sheets(sheetNames(x)) ' this will pass the sheet to your Demo sub to work on
next x

End Sub

Sub Demo(inputWS As Worksheet)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim path As String, fileName As String
Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
Dim outputWS As Worksheet

'set your sheets here
Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
rowCntr = 1

'get last rows from both sheets
lastRowInput = inputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = inputWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'copy data from columns AR, AS
inputWS.Range("AR1:AR11" & lastRowInput).Copy outputWS.Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```